# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 1000, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

I am having error with this :

> C:\Users\Akash\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow_lessons\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Akash/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow_lessons/TenFlow_01.py
>   2018-07-06 16:15:56.929521: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Akash/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow_lessons/TenFlow_01.py", line 45, in 
>       feed_dict={inputs: training_data['inputs'], targets: training_data['targets']})
>     File "C:\Users\Akash\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow_lessons\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "C:\Users\Akash\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow_lessons\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1111, in _run
>       str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
>   ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 1000, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Process finished with exit code 1

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

"""Data generation"""
obs = 1000
xs = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (obs, 1))
zs = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (obs, 1))
generated_inputs = np.stack((xs, zs))
noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (obs, 1))
generated_targets = 2 * xs - 3 * zs + 5 + noise

np.savez('TF_Intro', inputs=generated_inputs, targets=generated_targets)

# solving with tensorflow
input_size = 2
output_size = 1

# outlining the model
inputs = tf.placeholder('float', [None, input_size])  # feeds data to TF_intro file's input column
targets = tf.placeholder('float', [None, output_size])  # same as above to output column

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([input_size, output_size], minval=-0.1, maxval=0.1))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([output_size], minval=-0.1, maxval=0.1))

outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, weights) + biases  # matmul is same concpt like dotproduct but its for tensors

"""Choosing objective function and optimization methods"""
mean_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=targets, predictions=outputs) / 2.
optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.02).minimize(mean_loss)

"""prepare for execute"""
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

"""initialisation of variables"""
initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()  # initialises all tensor objects marked as variables
sess.run(initializer)

"""Load training data"""
training_data = np.load('TF_Intro.npz')

"""learning"""
for e in range(100):
    _, curr_loss = sess.run([optimize, mean_loss],
                            feed_dict={inputs: training_data['inputs'],
                                       targets: training_data['targets']})
    print(curr_loss)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a type of error related to non-matching shapes of tensors, read the error message carefully:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 1000, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

If you debug a little bit your code, you will immediately notice that the error is due to the fact that `training_data['inputs']` has shape `(2, 1000, 1)` whereas `inputs` has shape `(?, 2)`. Given that they have different shapes, you cannot "feed" `training_data['inputs']` for `inputs`.

*The solution to this problem depends on what you actually want to do*.

If you want to "concatenate" `xs` and `zs`, instead of using `generated_inputs = np.stack((xs, zs))`, you need `generated_inputs = tf.concat([xs, zs], 1)`. In that case, `generated_inputs` will have shape `(1000, 2)`, so it can be fed as `inputs` (which has shape `(?, 2)`).

However, if you replace `generated_inputs = np.stack((xs, zs))` with `generated_inputs = tf.concat([xs, zs], 1)`, you will get another error:

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup SwigPyObject on builtins failed

which is probably due to the fact that the arrays/variables you save with `np.savez` must have the same dimension (or maybe because we would be attempting to save a matrix?). You can solve this problem e.g. by saving `xs` and `zs` separately. So, instead of `np.savez('TF_Intro', inputs = generated_inputs, targets=generated_targets)`, you may have `np.savez('TF_Intro', xs=xs, zs=zs, targets=generated_targets)`. Then, before executing the `run` method (in the session), you can concatenate `xs` and `zs`. For example, using the following code

```
...

for e in range(100):
    xs = training_data['xs']
    zs = training_data['zs']
    X = np.concatenate((xs, zs), axis=1)
    T = training_data['targets']

    _, curr_loss = sess.run([optimize, mean_loss],
                            feed_dict={inputs: X,
                                       targets: T})
    print(curr_loss)
```

**Note**: If you perform the changes I have suggested, your code will compile and execute without errors, but I have no idea if this is what you want to achieve with your code and I don't want to dwell on it.

By the way, why are you generating inputs and targets, storing them, and then reading them from a file? Why not just simply using the inputs and targets directly (in this case)?